# First cohomology with coefficients in local system

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space. $G = \pi_1 (X)$ fundamental group. Local systems on $X$ are in one to one correspondence to representations of $G$. Let $V$ be a representations of $G$. $L$ - corresponding local system on $X$.

Also we can consider $BG$. By definition $\pi_1(BG) = G$. So $V$ defines a local system $\mathscr{L}$ on $BG$.

**Question** Is $H^1(X , L )$ isomorphic to $H^1(BG , \mathscr{L}) $?

**Comment** It is definitely fails for higher cohomology (e.g. there are simply connected spaces with higher cohomologies). But this holds for zero cohomology (they are just invariants).

Comment: What is $M$ here?

Comment: Thank you. My $M$ is actually $X$. I already edit my question.

Comment: Good question. It's true for constant local systems at least.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if $X$ is CW. You can build a model for $BG$ by attaching cells of dimension at least 3 to $X$. The local system on $X$ extends uniquely to $BG$, and the corresponding chain complex is only changed in degrees three and above. In particular, first cohomology is unchanged.

In particular this group may be calculated in terms of crossed homomorphisms.